# Where to keep data (model) for a view in Eclipse RCP?

Tags: java, eclipse, swt, eclipse-rcp

I have a third-party class (suppose it is some tree-like container).

How to implement a view for it correctly? I see no MVC-like methods in `ViewPart` class. For example, there is no `setModel()` method like in Swing.

In Hello World view example, they just set some hardcoded text to a label. Where should I keep data in real-life example?

**UPDATE**

Suppose I have a good MVC widget with `setModel()` method and which is named `MyGreatWidget()`.

This does not remove the question.

I would write this case:

```
public void createPartControl(Composite parent) {
     widget = new MyGreatWidget(parent);
     widget.setModel(... // where to get data?
  }
```

**UPDATE 2**

In other words: is there any convenient place in Eclipse platform where to keep application- or session- scoped data?

**UPDATE 3**

My question is where to keep deserialized objects, which are already in memory.

In other words: does RCP **view** disobey model-**view**-controller pattern?

**UPDATE 4**

Let's rephrase the question: to which areas `createPartControl()` method can access?

1) It's parameter `Composite parent`

2) Any static method of any class

3) something else?

Can it access application instance? or workbench instance? may be application context? or some other instance where I could put data it needs to draw?

Answer (score 3):

My understanding of your problem is following:

- Some kind of user's interaction causes your view/editor to be shown.
- Eclipse framework starts creating a content (for instance, `createPartControl()` method you have specified). At this point you should initialize all your great widgets and necessary controls (make them available within your UI part). You can make them private instances of a View class or build your own framework which keeps track of controls, for example in some Map. Also, set content providers for Viewers at this step.
- When UI is created, you could start filling your widgets with data (read data from files, make a request to the server etc.). It can be performed in the background job, to have more responsive UI. Note, that data loading mechanism (and mechanism which notifies UI about data has been loaded) varies from app to app, so you have to invent our own wheel for that. **It is the step, where you create your model.** It is up to you, where you keep it (*usually it is enough to just have it as an instance in your view*). Also, please remember, that you don't need to load data for comboboxes right away, as you can stick with lazy loading solution (use ComboViewer and ContentProvider).
- Once data is loaded you can populate widgets with it, by invoking related methods (like `setText()` for a Label widget and so on)
- Personally, I like using [JFace data binding mechanism](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseDataBinding/article.html) to populate widgets with data and keep model up to date, without having to each time write code to fetch data from widgets and write it back to the model, before saving the model.

Edit: btw, I think there is no need to introduce controller layer for a fat client applications, as there is no need to control creation of the UI, since creation of correct views is strictly defined by your code, which is already presented client's machine. There is no need to ask server to return a view (unlike in web applications), you only ask it to return some data (model).

Hope this somehow helps.

Answer (score 2):

> How to implement a view for it correctly? I see no MVC-like methods in ViewPart class. For example, there is no setModel() method like in Swing.

You have to do that yourself. Futhermore, you don't set a model on the view itself, rather on widgets that are connected with your own framework.

> In Hello World view example, they just set some hardcoded text to a label. Where should I keep data in real-life example?

Serializable wrappers, POJOs that go into a database etc.

Your question is a bit vague, you will have to be more specific if you didn't understand my answer.

---

**Edit 1:**

No. Eclipse RCP does not handle data sources. It has lightweight mechanics which handle things like [preferences](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipsePreferences/article.html). For your own data, you'll have to serialize your stuff.

Comment: I don't understand, why are you speaking about serialization? My question is where to keep deserialized objects, in memory.

Comment: @SuzanCioc ... you just keep them in memory. You instantiate the model object and use it.

Comment: So, I should not use MVC pattern and should mix view with a model, right? Eclipse platform does not tend me to use MVC right?

Comment: @SuzanCioc Maybe [this](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wa-eclipsemvc/) will help.

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand your practical question. I struggled with the same issue.

When starting a new Eclipse RCP project, you construct a lot of views which manipulate a single Model. You wonder how you should store the actual model. This is because Eclipse uses the 'workspace' paradigm, which is a single directory that is opened when you launch the framework. Everything else springs forth from this workbench: projects, files that are edited, and so on.

When you construct your own application, you will struggle to find a good alternative. Typically, applications are file-based, with paradigms like 'Open', 'New File', 'Save As' or 'Close'. Multiple views manipulate this single 'file'.

I followed the path/reasoning below:

- Have a 'root' or 'main' view that is always present. This view initializes and contains your model. When opening or closing a file, you change the reference in this 'main' view.
- This does not hold for all cases. Therefore, I used the 'Input' field of the WorkbenchPage. This has the added benefit of allowing multiple windows. A single Page (and single Input) corresponds to a single window. However, you can only find your Model from the UI thread, which will give you problems in asynchronous jobs for example.
- Finally, I settled on using the EditingDomain framework. You can recover an EditingDomain based on it's ID. I load my model in this EditingDomain and can therefore easily access it from any context, even when the GUI thread is not available anymore (e.g. asynchronous Jobs).